# how to debug upstart if it hangs while root is read-only?

Tags: boot, mount, upstart

I am trying to debug an unsecessful/hung-up system start (upstart) on 14.04.2 LTS. root is an ext4 filesystem in a luks container. filesystems are in clean state.

The boot process stops after upstart-socket-bridge, (not necessarily after that specific service, e.g. when cups-daemon was installed, it stoped after that). `init -v` isnt very helpful either. The only log entry that isnt merely logging the start/stop of various services is one about udev right before init.

```
Begin: Running /scripts/init-bottom ... done.
udev exit failed --rc=2
```

(Edit) Remounting the root rw initially appeared to be always leading to a clean boot, but fact is, its kinda unpredictable and i had failed and successful boots either way. wut?

*Observation: Everything appears to be fine, the system simply doesnt remounts the root writable or continues the boot.*

**Q: *How do i figure which service is at fault for getting the boot process stuck?***

---

### Update: Spawning a second shell via getty one can run `initctl list` after it hangs up, these are the running jobs

```
mountnfs-bootclean.sh start/running
udev start/running, process 438
upstart-udev-bridge start/running, process 432
plymouth start/running, process 122
resolvconf start/running
ssh start/running, process 767 <-- this one was manually started
mountall start/running, process 337
mountkernfs.sh start/running
mountnfs.sh start/running
bootmisc.sh start/running
upstart-socket-bridge start/running, process 745**
cryptdisks start/running
mountdevsubfs.sh start/running
mtab.sh start/running
network-interface (lo) start/running
network-interface (eth0) start/running
plymouth-ready (startup) start/running, process 315
plymouth-upstart-bridge start/running, process 316
mountall-bootclean.sh start/running
network-interface-security (network-interface/eth0) start/running
network-interface-security (network-interface/lo) start/running
```

---

### Update 2:

- Reinstaling upstart and all its dependant packets (is a pain and) has no effect.
- Using the second console, i can just use `init 5` to get the stuck
  system to continue boot normally.
- the system now got stuck even if i manually remounted the root rw (or used the rw kernel parameter) - my initial observation that forcing the root writable works around the issue is incorrect

---

### Workaround:

It appears to be `ureadahead`s fault. Purging it resulted in 5 clean boots withouth any issue. I'll just leave the question (and the 100 extra rep) open for anyone interested or knowing an answer for the original question: How, if not by random trial, i could have figured this out.

Comment: You could do a `grep` on the string `start on` for the .conf files of the services that **have** started, then for the services that **haven't** started, and see if that gives you any clue. For instance I notice that both `mountall-bootclean.sh` and `udev` are started on the `virtual-filesystems` event, so that means all [virtual filesystems](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man7/virtual-filesystems.7.html) were mounted at that time.

Comment: have you check the upstart log ? at /var/log/upstart/your_upstart_command

Comment: Mind you that not all of the services with status `stop/waiting` *ought to* have started at boot time.

Comment: For what it's worth I posted my `initctl list` [here](http://jpst.it/xwrb).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For reference, the (unsuccessful) debug steps i tried, which my however be useful to others:**

- get another debian-like system that does boot (e.g. a live ubuntu on a bootable usb pen drive) and make configuration or software changes to the examined system using chroot. use qemu-static to be able to do this on a system with differing architecture.
- install a standalone shell like `sash`, then change your kernel command line (use the e key in grub or edit grub.cfg/cmdline.txt) and add `init=/bin/sash`, reboot, examine the situation on that shell and only then use `exec init` to continue booting
- use `init` with the `-v` switch to increase logging
- mount the root filesystem writable early (e.g. add 'rw' to the kernel command line, `mount -o remount,rw /` before executing init) - this allows for more logging
- examine `/var/log/upstart`
- start an extra terminal on tty2 before executing init, e.g. `getty -n -l /bin/bash 38400 tty2 &` - this helps examining the status the system is in (e.g. `ps -Af`, `iotop`)
- use `initctl list` to figure out which services are in which state